# Awesome WM scratchpad with terminator

Tags: linux, terminal, awesome-wm, terminator

I've recently started using Awesome WM and trying to recreate a [Yakuake](http://extragear.kde.org/apps/yakuake/)-like experience I found the [Scratchpad manager](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Scratchpad_manager).

I've tried several configurations to make it work with terminator, and so far the only one that approaches working is this:

```
 awful.key({ modkey }, "F11", function () scratch.drop("terminator") end),
```

So when I press the trigger, terminator is opened but it's resized (or moved, I can't tell) to the top of the screen and with a height of 1 pixel. If I use `gnome-terminal` instead of terminator, it works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the position and dimensions as you need in scratch.drop.

The format is (app, Y, X, width, height).

```
awful.key({ modkey }, "F11", function () scratch.drop("terminator", "top", "center", 720, 400) end),
```